# c# FileSystemWatcher stops firing events after sometime

Tags: c#

I want to track file changes of particular path and I am pretty much done with the code which is now working fine.it is tracking file creation , renamed and changed .

My problem is when I am launching Filesystemwatcher it's working fine but after some time its stop working i.e it stops firing creation ,deleted and changed event.

Can anybody help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code
lstFolder is my multiple path list

```
this.listFileSystemWatcher = new List();

            // Loop the list to process each of the folder specifications found
            if (lstFolder.Count > 0)// check if path is available to watch else exit file watcher
            {
                foreach (CustomFolderSettings customFolder in lstFolder)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(customFolder.FWPath);
                    // Checks whether the folder is enabled and
                    // also the directory is a valid location
                    if (dir.Exists)//customFolder.FolderEnabled && 
                    {
                        customFolder.AllowedFiles = customFolder.FWExtension;// setting extension to allowed filw extension to log .
                        foreach (var strExt in customFolder.FWExtension.Split(','))
                        {

                            // Creates a new instance of FileSystemWatcher
                            //FileSystemWatcher fileSWatch = new FileSystemWatcher();
                             this.fileSWatch = new FileSystemWatcher();
                            // Sets the filter
                            fileSWatch.Filter = strExt;// customFolder.FolderFilter;
                                                       // Sets the folder location
                            fileSWatch.Path = customFolder.FWPath;
                            fileSWatch.InternalBufferSize = 64000;
                            // Sets the action to be executed
                            StringBuilder actionToExecute = new StringBuilder(customFolder.ExecutableFile);
                            // List of arguments
                            StringBuilder actionArguments = new StringBuilder(customFolder.ExecutableArguments);
                            // Subscribe to notify filters
                            fileSWatch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                            // Associate the events that will be triggered when a new file Created,Changed,Deleted,Renamed //
                            // is added to the monitored folder, using a lambda expression                   
                            fileSWatch.Created += (senderObj, fileSysArgs) => fileSWatch_Created(senderObj, fileSysArgs, actionToExecute.ToString(), customFolder.AllowedFiles);
                            fileSWatch.Changed += (senderObj, fileSysArgs) => fileSWatch_Changed(senderObj, fileSysArgs, actionToExecute.ToString(), customFolder.AllowedFiles);

                            fileSWatch.Deleted += (senderObj, fileSysArgs) => fileSWatch_Deleted(senderObj, fileSysArgs, actionToExecute.ToString(), customFolder.AllowedFiles);
                            fileSWatch.Renamed += (senderObj, fileSysArgs) => fileSWatch_Renamed(senderObj, fileSysArgs, actionToExecute.ToString(), customFolder.AllowedFiles);
                            fileSWatch.Error += (senderObj, fileSysArgs) => fileSWatch_Error(senderObj, fileSysArgs, actionToExecute.ToString(), customFolder.AllowedFiles);


                            // will track changes in sub-folders as well
                            fileSWatch.IncludeSubdirectories = customFolder.FWSubFolders;
                            // Begin watching
                            fileSWatch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


                            // Add the systemWatcher to the list
                            listFileSystemWatcher.Add(fileSWatch);
                            GC.KeepAlive(fileSWatch);
                            GC.KeepAlive(listFileSystemWatcher);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
```

Comment: Does it stop working altogether or drop events?

Comment: that i am unable to understand. after some idle time it does not able to track file changes.

Comment: I think I read some moths/years ago something similar. The problem was set to be a very huge buffer. I see you use `fileSWatch.InternalBufferSize`. Try to change the value, or remove it. I'm not sure what was the question from long ago, but I think the speed was slow because of big buffer _(unfortunately I do not remember whether it has also the problem with stopping of events)_.

Comment: _(After Saruman response)_ When you have too many changes in files and it is not possible to use specified filtering, try to rework the functions `fileSWatch_*` to only collect the events _(e.g. to `List`)_ and process the information in a lower priority thread. This should at least allow you to clear the buffer at faster speed. But remember, long buffer means slower processing _(in system)_.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use

```
GC.KeepAlive(fileSWatch);
GC.KeepAlive(listFileSystemWatcher);
```

Create a `List<FileSystemWatcher>` and store each one instead

Also have a look at

> [Events and Buffer Sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2#constructors)
>
> Note that several factors can affect which file system change events
>   are raised, as described by the following:
>
> - Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several
>     OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised.
>     Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple
>     operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some
>     applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional
>     file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.
> - The FileSystemWatcher can watch disks as long as they are not switched or removed. The FileSystemWatcher does not raise events for
>     CDs and DVDs, because time stamps and properties cannot change. Remote
>     computers must have one of the required platforms installed for the
>     component to function properly.
> - If multiple FileSystemWatcher objects are watching the same UNC path in Windows XP prior to Service Pack 1, or Windows 2000 SP2 or earlier,
>     then only one of the objects will raise an event. On machines running
>     Windows XP SP1 and newer, Windows 2000 SP3 or newer or Windows Server
>     2003, all FileSystemWatcher objects will raise the appropriate events.
>
> Note that a FileSystemWatcher may miss an event when the buffer size
>   is exceeded. To avoid missing events, follow these guidelines:
>
> - Increase the buffer size by setting the InternalBufferSize property.
> - Avoid watching files with long file names, because a long file name contributes to filling up the buffer. Consider renaming these files
>     using shorter names.
> - Keep your event handling code as short as possible.

[FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> **Remarks**
>
> You can set the buffer to 4 KB or larger, but it must not exceed 64
>   KB. If you try to set the InternalBufferSize property to less than
>   4096 bytes, your value is discarded and the InternalBufferSize
>   property is set to 4096 bytes. For best performance, use a multiple of
>   4 KB on Intel-based computers.
>
> The system notifies the component of file changes, and it stores those
>   changes in a buffer the component creates and passes to the APIs. Each
>   event can use up to 16 bytes of memory, not including the file name.
>   If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow.
>   This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory,
>   and it will only provide blanket notification.
>
> Increasing the size of the buffer can prevent missing file system
>   change events. However, increasing buffer size is expensive, because
>   it comes from non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so
>   keep the buffer as small as possible. To avoid a buffer overflow, use
>   the NotifyFilter and IncludeSubdirectories properties to filter out
>   unwanted change notifications.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: i have tried by removing fileSWatch.InternalBufferSize = 64000; but problem still remain.about GC i read somewhere GC forcefully destroying file watcher objects that might be one reason so i did it but problem didnt get solved.